# what ssl solution allow Server IP so any domains pointed to that will ssled?

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate

Is there any ssl solution based on Server IP so any domains pointed to that will be allowed?

We allow client to run our app on their domain for whilelabling and our app also require ssl as well.

So what type of ssl sholud i look for?

Comment: why downvote? is it wrong question on wrong place..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think about your question for a minute. If this product existed, it would allow anyone to impersonate any other domain. That is **precisely** what DV and EV certs are trying to prevent.

So no, what you want does not exist. You will need to provide some way for your customers to install their own key and signed certificate in your application.